# not jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to apply the jQuery `.serializeArray` on the `form` but not the elements which have the class `inactive`

```
const inputData = $('form:not[class="inactive"]').serializeArray();
```

Why is it failing and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: The error message you include does not come from the code you have included

Comment: @Jamiec thx. removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, to leave elements out of [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), you need to make them disabled or remove their `name`. So for instance:

```
const inputData = $('form')
                      .find('.inactive')
                      .prop("disabled", true)
                      .end()
                      .serializeArray();
```

That:

- Finds all forms
- Finds the inactive elements in them
- Ensures those elements are marked `disabled`
- Returns to the forms (`.end()`)
- ...and serializes their elements.

---

Re the `:not` selector you tried to use, there were a few problems:

1. You've used `[]` instead of `()` around the `:not` condition
2. You should use a class selector, not an attribute selector, when using classes
3. You were applying it to the `form`, not to elements *within* the form

But since you need to call `serializeArray` on the **form**, we need a different approach altogether (as above).

Answer (score 1):

When using a `:not` selector, keep the following things in mind:

1. use `()` for `:not` instead of `[]`
2. don't select `class` as an attribute, use a class selector
3. as you want to select the elements inside the `form` there need to be a space between `form` and `:not`, otherwise you will only select `all forms without .inactive class`

This would be a correct element selector:

```
const inputData = $('form :not(.inactive)');
```

To use `serializeArray` correctly, take a look at @T.J.Crowder's answer!

Comment: Actually, there's a third thing: It needs a space after `form`, as the OP said *"but not the elements which have the class inactive"* What's there now will just not select a **form** with that class. In fact, although right in the specifics, this doesn't actually answer the question.